# FFmpeg record live stream and make mp4 file closer to now to play at html5 video and should updated quickly

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

Now I am developing video clipping system with PHP and FFMpeg.
Recording live stream from media server with rtmp protocol.
Let's suppose we are recording football and I want make highlight soon.
so I can see live streams and also able to clip video.
Please help me if anyone have idea.

Reference URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x61rge3Q3mw

Thank you.
Angel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really quite complicated Task.
But I did like this.

1. Started record from given URL.
2. Make ts files per minute.(gave file format, easy to converted to mp4)
3. Concatenate ts files and made it to mp4( It took really small time)
4. Then I played mp4 files.

Was Awesome.